# will it increase request data size when using r.js to minimize all modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs, minify, r.js

For example:

On page A I require my module A which require `jQuery, underscore`.

```
define('moudleA', ['jQuery', 'underscore'], function.....);
require(['moduleA'], .....)
```

On page B I require my module B which require `jQuery, something`.

```
define('moudleA', ['jQuery', 'underscore'], function.....);
require(['moduleA'], .....)
```

Both two page require `jQuery`, If I don't concat and minify them, the first page(A/B) will load `jQuery` normally, but when I jump to the other page(B/A), browser will use cached `jQuery` instead of loading it from server again(304 state code).

But on the other hand, the concated and minified version will both have `jQuery` code and be requested from server because they stay in different files (pageA.min.js | pageB.min.js).

If this is right, how can we solve this?

Thanks in advance. :-)

**Solution**

This seem to be a solution: [example-multipage](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)

Comment: It might be an idea to combine all shared libraries into one module, separate from the page-specific scripts. This way, you can use one and the same module for all your pages, which should benefit the caching.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah. This seems is a good way. Thanks.